# Tag Duplicate close on old question

Tags: bug, status-completed, closing-questions

A few hours ago, I voted to close this question for being a duplicate:

[How did Obi-Wan know Darth Vader was Anakin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35576/how-did-obi-wan-know-darth-vader-was-anakin?noredirect=1][1])

It closed immediately, despite the fact that I only have a gold tag badge for [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek), not [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars).

Apparently the post did (at one point) have a [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) tag but that was removed over a year ago. So why am I still able to close it on my own?

Comment: I remember reading a similar question where it was stated that this behavior was intentional so that a person is prevented from avoiding a close by just removing a tag. Unfortunately, I can't find the question at the moment so I can't link to it.

Comment: @amaranth Thanks for the heads-up. I'd noticed the change, but hadn't remembered this question. (I also left [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now#comment913494_268281) on that main meta thread which Valorum may find relevant.)

Comment: Tagging [meta-tag:status-completed] since you now have a gold [tag:star-wars] tag badge as well :-P

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Next up "Movies". The stupidest gold badge of all.

Answer (score 8):

Update: The behavior in question has been changed, and the original situation should not happen under current (7/2016) rules:

> We have changed the behavior of the dupehammer. It now lets you single-handedly close as duplicate unless you have participated in editing the tag (either by adding the tag yourself, or approving an edit that did).

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308573

---

Original answer:

In order to prevent abuse of the dupehammer, the dupehammer applies only to those tags present when the question was asked.

From [the MSE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212):

> - You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was *originally asked* with a tag you have a gold badge for.

Comment: Surely if the tag has been removed, this is no longer valid.

Comment: Perhaps. You could post a feature request on MSE if you want.

Comment: So, not a bug just a weird feature.

Comment: Did you come up with "duperhammer"? Love it

Comment: @DVK - Similar to a banhammer; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banhammer

Comment: @Richard - I've been on the internet long enough to know what Banhammer is, thankyouverymuch :)

Comment: @DVK - And been on the receiving end of one, if memory serves :-)

Comment: @DVK http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dupehammer

Comment: Hmm. So, if I'm posting a question, and I **don't** want any random clown with a gold badge to be able to close it as a duplicate, all I have to do is post the question with some silly tag, wait five minutes, and then edit in the appropriate tags?